# Retrofit2 GET request with Id

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to make a request in my android project. The url is this one

"https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?includeNutrition=false"

I am using retrofit 2 but i can't figure out how to make it work.

Here is what i tried to do.

I get the id of a recipe and call this function passing the id.

```
 fun applyQueryById(recipeId: Int): String{
   val  searchByIdQuery = "${recipeId}/information?includeNutrition=false&apiKey=${API_KEY}"
    return searchByIdQuery
}
```

And the GET request is this one

```
   @GET("/recipes/")
suspend fun getRecipeById(
    @Query("id") searchById:String
):Response<PersonalizedRecipeResult>
```

I thinks that because the id is in the middle, making a raw string like i am doing is not a good idea. if anyone could suggest something different I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@Query("id")` which will ad the value as query.

From your example, I can see that you want to use `@Path`

You can use it like this

```
   @GET("/recipes/{id}")
   suspend fun getRecipeById(
      @Path("id") searchById:String
   ):Response<PersonalizedRecipeResult>
```

by this way the `searchById` will be replaced with `{id}` in your example call

Comment: Okey! I thought about that but then how can i append the remaining end point to the same query (information?includeNutrition=false"). Many many thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi mate! Finally i figure out how to do it! I used what you showed to me and a simple @QueryMap as the second parameter. Many thanks from Spain! Wish you the best

Comment: Hey @Robert glad it is worked, if you found my answer useful please mark it as answer ;)

Comment: Done @Mustafa!! Is the first time I ask here. i didn't know :)

Comment: @Robert no worries thank you :)